# How do I recreate the smooth scrolling effect that I found on this site in jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the site I'm talking about: http://hlkagency.com/.

Basically, I love the scrolling effect on tapping the up and down arrow keys. Other smooth scrolling libraries I found were too slow and clunky. I want to make something that works exactly like this.

I tried going through the minified script used on the page after beautifying it, but there just seems to be a whole lot going on.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling

Comment: You could probably try out something using css3 alongside jquery. Css3 animations are smooth.

Answer (score 0):

That's a Parallax style scrolling. Like @RobertHarvey pointed on his comment. There are so many libraries since it has become very popular. This [Library](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax) has examples of how it can be implemented. If you do a google search on parallax libraries for JS you will find a ton.